# C++ win32 Get ScrollBar contol size

Tags: c++, winapi

[image: example]

To custom-draw a whole scrollbar, is there a way to get the rectangles of the scrollbar's parts (`SB_LINEUP`, `SB_LINEDOWN`, `SB_THUMBTRACK`, etc)?

```
mainHwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, wc.lpszClassName, WC_WINDOW,
        WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL, 600, 400, 700, 380, nullptr, 0, wc.hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: have you looked at the [`SBM_GETSCROLLBARINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/sbm-getscrollbarinfo) and [`SBM_GETSCROLLINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/sbm-getscrollinfo) messages yet?

Comment: Reading the question I would have thought what you really want is `SystemParametersInfoW` with `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` to retrieve `iScrollWidth` and `iScrollHeight`, and the implement scrolling *entirely* by yourself (so no `WS_VSCROLL` or anything). It's not trivial but it's easier than you might think. Easier than trying to deal with all the contingencies of what Windows may or may not insist on doing with the standard scroll bars anyway...

Comment: I am getting frustrated with the built-in control(WS_VSCROLL) to draw, so I decided to try and make it from scratch :)

Answer (score 1):

Onpaint

```
    case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps{};
    HDC dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    int count;
    int lineCount = 0;
    int startLine = GetScrollPos(hwnd, SB_VERT);
    int endLine = startLine + rows;
    int strLength = 0;
    CHAR buf[10];
    SetTextColor(dc, RGB(190, 190, 190));
    SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
    for (count = startLine; count < endLine; count++) {
        strLength = sprintf(buf, "%d", count);
        TextOut(dc, 12, lineCount, buf, strLength);
        lineCount = lineCount + fontHeight;
    }
    SCROLLBARINFO info{};
    info.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLBARINFO);
    GetScrollBarInfo(hwnd, OBJID_VSCROLL, &info);

    RECT rc = info.rcScrollBar;
    MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, hwnd, (POINT*)&rc, 2);
    rc.left -= 50;
    FillRect(dc, &rc, br);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}break;
```

@Remy Lebeau
@beothunder

thx a lot:)

i gotta try avoid default paint :(

[simple unittest VS2017](https://pastebin.com/3gnFHXLA)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).